# Создание функций в HIVE

Tags: sql, функции, процедуры, hadoop, hive

Через sql запрос в HIVE я получаю некоторое значение трех полей.

- 1 поле - название функции
- 2 поле - название поля в другой таблице,
- 3 поле - также название поля в другой таблицы.

К примеру SUM, A1,A5. Теперь в HIVE нужно выполнить это функцию с этими полями. Исходя из вышеуказанного примера нужно суммировать все поля между от A1 до А5. Причем важно чтобы все делалось автоматически. Но у меня нет никакой идей в какую сторону двигаться. Может кто даст направление?

Comment: Как вы используете Hive - програмно т.е. используя JAVA/Scala/Python/etc. или чистый SQL, например в `beeline`?

Comment: Beeline в интеграции с ODI. Но ODI это не принципиално. Чаще всего чистый SQL.

Comment: Не уверен, что это можно сделать в чистом SQL... Скорее всего придется динамически собирать SQL на основе результата предыдущего запроса. Задача эта несложная, если вы пользуютесь JAVA / Scala / Python или другим языком программирования...